# Getting an error after every iPhone sync that some items could not be found

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

After every sync, I am alerted that two items could not be transferred because they could not be found. That is not surprising to me: they are two podcast episodes which were deleted long ago and I don't even subscribe to those podcasts anymore. However, for some reasons there seems to be some data of them stuck and I'd like to get rid of that.

- Downloading the episodes again and then deleting them would have been the first thing to try, but they are no longer available.
- When I edit the iTunes Music Library.xml to remove the entries for those files and the corresponding key from all playlists, that does not help at all.

Since then I've seen at support.apple.com/kb/ht1660 that the relevant information is probably saved in the iTunes Library.itl file, which I cannot edit because it is not using xml. Any suggestions what I could do? I don't want to disable the alert, because generally I'd like to be notified when things go missing.

Comment: Have you tried disabling podcast syncing and then syncing the phone?

Comment: You could have written that as an answer ;) Turning it off, syncing, turning it on and syncing again seems to have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, try disabling podcast sync, then syncing the phone without the podcasts and re-enabling podcasts sync again.